# Transforming one XML document into another with C++

Tags: c++, xml, xslt

What would be a straightforward way to transform a source XML document into a destination XML document. There are only small differences between source and destination: Specifically I want to delete the first `UnitIDRecord`-Node within each `UnitIDGroup`-Node.

- What would be the appropriate model for this task DOM or SAX?
- What XML-library would best fit this problem (which guarantees that the source and destination only differs in the deleted nodes, no missing namespace, attributes, encoding, ...)?
- I read about `XSLT`, could this be an option?

The XML document looks like following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExPostInformationRealGeneration xmlns="http://schemas.seven2one.de/EEX/TransparencyPlatform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.seven2one.de/EEX/TransparencyPlatform EEXTransparencyPlatform.xsd">
    <DispatcherID>XYZ</DispatcherID>
    <CreationDateTime>2012-05-22T13:57:00Z</CreationDateTime>
    <MessageText>1 - Positiv - Meldung mit Quality-Tag - L000</MessageText>
    <UnitIDGroup>
        <UnitID>E110200-001</UnitID>
        <UnitIDRecord><Quantity>16.9</Quantity><Starttime>2008-04-30T22:00:00Z</Starttime><Period>PT1H</Period><MessageText></MessageText></UnitIDRecord>
        <UnitIDRecord><Quantity>16.6</Quantity><Starttime>2008-04-30T23:00:00Z</Starttime><Period>PT1H</Period><MessageText></MessageText></UnitIDRecord>
        <UnitIDRecord><Quantity>16.4</Quantity><Starttime>2008-05-01T00:00:00Z</Starttime><Period>PT1H</Period><MessageText></MessageText></UnitIDRecord>
    </UnitIDGroup>
    <UnitIDGroup>
        <UnitID>E110200-002</UnitID>
        <UnitIDRecord><Quantity>16.9</Quantity><Starttime>2008-04-30T22:00:00Z</Starttime><Period>PT1H</Period><MessageText></MessageText></UnitIDRecord>
        <UnitIDRecord><Quantity>16.6</Quantity><Starttime>2008-04-30T23:00:00Z</Starttime><Period>PT1H</Period><MessageText></MessageText></UnitIDRecord>
        <UnitIDRecord><Quantity>16.4</Quantity><Starttime>2008-05-01T00:00:00Z</Starttime><Period>PT1H</Period><MessageText></MessageText></UnitIDRecord>
    </UnitIDGroup>
    <UnitIDGroup>
        <UnitID>E110201-001</UnitID>
        <UnitIDRecord><Quantity>7.0</Quantity><Starttime>2008-04-30T22:00:00Z</Starttime><Period>PT1H</Period><MessageText></MessageText></UnitIDRecord>
        <UnitIDRecord><Quantity>7.1</Quantity><Starttime>2008-04-30T23:00:00Z</Starttime><Period>PT1H</Period><MessageText></MessageText></UnitIDRecord>
        <UnitIDRecord><Quantity>7.1</Quantity><Starttime>2008-05-01T00:00:00Z</Starttime><Period>PT1H</Period><MessageText></MessageText></UnitIDRecord>
    </UnitIDGroup>
    <!-- other UnitIDGroup elements -->
</ExPostInformationRealGeneration>
```

Comment: Q: I read about XSLT, could this be an option?  A: Yes.  In fact, it's probably the *preferred* option :)  If you happen to be on Windows, here's a good tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms759206%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It should happen on Windows, thank you for the tutorial. It seems, that I can take the example from the link and what remains is writing the appropriate XSL file (hope this is not too difficult :-).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the possibility of reading the file in as strings and writing the string out to another file if it matches your criteria. That's a 5 line program and avoids any parsing etc. It will run quickly and is simple. But, it is specific to this problem and not reusable. I offer this therefore as a suggestion not the correct solution!